# Protege Using swrl:equal to compare the values of datatype property

Tags: owl, swrl

I am building an ontology of 3 classes :

1. Messages
2. Ham
3. Spam

2 dataproperties , domain : Messages  and range xsd:string :

1. hasInterest
2. hasCategory

2 SWRL Rules:
Message(?x),hasInterest(?x,?a),hasCategory(?x,?b), swrl:equal(?a,?b) ->Ham(?x)

Message(?x),hasInterest(?x,?a),hasCategory(?x,?b), swrl:notEqual(?a?b) ->Spam(?x)

I want to classify instances of class Message to class Spam or Ham ; if the hasCategory value ( message category) is equal to the hasInterest value ( user interests) then the message is ham else spam

This worked correctly If I have 1 message category and  1 interest
ex:
m1 hasInterests sports
m1 hasCategory sports

So what If I have a list of iterests or categories ex:
Each message has more than 1 interests {sports, movies}
Each message has more than 1 category {movies , politics}

I want to say if both lists intersect then the message is ham so the swrl:equal did not work how can i define it to compare all the individuals

What I did is repeating the hasInterests and hasCategory depending on the individual values I mean defining manually the list and it worked , is there another automatic way using a list of strings and how to compare them in swrl ?

Answer (score 1):

SWRL Built-Ins for Strings (http://www.daml.org/rules/proposal/builtins.html) only support simple string functions.
In your model you can model a message individual `m1` with many interests and many categories like this:

```
m1 hasInterests "sports", m1 hasInterests "movies" 
m1 hasCategory "sports", m1 m1 hasCategory "movies"
```

and with your rule

```
Message(?x),hasInterest(?x,?a),hasCategory(?x,?b), swrl:equal(?a,?b) ->Ham(?x)
```

every message with at least one interest equal to a category becomes `Ham`.

Perhaps useful hint to find number of interests but with the SQWRL Query:

```
Message(?x) ^ hasInterest(?x,?a) → sqwrl:select(?x) ^ sqwrl:count(?a)
```